# Como solucionar error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'V' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy trayendo una lista en formato JSON la almaceno en una variable y funciona todo bien, el problema es cuando intento utilizar es variable en otro lado me aparece Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'V' of undefined, la V se trae de la lista.

Esta es la linea en la que me genera el error.

```
elementa = video.video[i].V;
```

Lo mas curioso es que eso esta dentro de un for y asu vez dentro de if, la cosa es cuando incremento la variable de comparcion del if a mas de 20 me lanza ese error

```
for(var i = 0; i <= long.length; i++){
        if (i <= 30) {
            elementa = video.video[i].V;
            itemsa.push('<img id="' + elementa.toLowerCase().replace('.mp4', '') + '" src="http://localhost:700/proyecto-daniel/assets/web/img/if_male3_403019.png" alt="" >');
        }
    }
```

Como vemos, la variable se encuentra en 30 y lanza el error, si trato de utilizarlo en otro lado me genera el mismo error. alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto

Al realizar un log del JSON este es el resultado, como ven si se encuentra V
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu problema es que intentas acceder a una posición del array que no existe. Para solucionar eso tienes dos opciones:

Opción 1: Cambiar el if

```
if (i <= video.video.length)
```

Opción 2: cambiar el for:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= video.video.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Has mirado que en todas las posiciones del JSON exista la propiedad V.

Podrías modificar el IF de la siguiente forma:

```
If(video.video[i].hasOwnProperty('V'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que los array empiezan en la posición 0, por lo tanto no existe la posición array[array.length], te aconsejaría que modificaras tu for usando el simbolo "<" y no el "<=" ya que estás accediendo a una posición inválida del array.